# Powershell. Need help importing hostnames from .csv. The rest of this works

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to figure out how to correct this script I've wrote. I know it is something wrong with the way it is importing the list of hostnames. I don't know how to fix it.

Part 1: This is supposed to import a .csv with the hostnames and dig the registry for the application's uninstall information, put it into an array, and export into .csv's for later use. Also it creates .txt files in order to later compare the applications on the system to a baseline.

```
$path = "\\path"
$computers = Import-Csv -Path "\\Path\hostnames.csv"
$array = @()
foreach($pc in $computers)
    {
    $computername = $pc.computername
    #$computername = "KNOWN_HOSTNAME" #test line for one system
    $UninstallKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall"
    $reg = [microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine',$computername)
    $regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($UninstallKey)
    $subkeys = $regkey.GetSubKeyNames()
    foreach($key in $subkeys)
        {
        $thisKey=$UninstallKey+"\\"+$key 
        $thisSubKey=$reg.OpenSubKey($thisKey) 
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ComputerName" -Value $computername
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayName"))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayVersion" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("DisplayVersion"))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Publisher" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("Publisher"))
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "InstallDate" -Value $($thisSubKey.GetValue("InstallDate"))
        $array += $obj
        $ExportArray = $array | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } | 
            select ComputerName , DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate
        $ExportArray | 
            Export-csv $path\$computername.csv -NoTypeInformation
        $ExportArray2 = $array | 
            Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } | 
            select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher
        $ExportArray2 | 
            Export-csv $path\$computername.txt -NoTypeInformation
        } 
    }
```

Part 2: This portion compiles the .csv's into one excel document for reporting

```
$csvs = Get-ChildItem $path\* -Include *.csv
$outputfilename = "Network_" + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd)
$excelapp = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$excelapp.sheetsInNewWorkbook = $csvs.Count
$xlsx = $excelapp.Workbooks.Add()
$sheet=1
foreach ($csv in $csvs)
    {
    $row=1
    $column=1
    $worksheet = $xlsx.Worksheets.Item($sheet)
    $worksheet.Name = $csv.Name
    $file = (Get-Content $csv.PSPath | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ""})
    foreach($line in $file)
        {
        $linecontents = $line -split ‘,(?!\s*\w+”)’
        foreach($cell in $linecontents)
            {
            $worksheet.Cells.Item($row,$column) = $cell
            $column++
            }
        $column = 1
        $row++
        }
    $sheet++
    }
$output = $path + “\” + $outputfilename + ".xlsx"
$xlsx.SaveAs($output)
$excelapp.quit()
```

Part 3: This portion loads up a baseline, and the .txt's created preciously, and checks for differences in the files. (also deletes blank ouput files)

```
$bline = Get-ChildItem $path\* -Include Baseline.txt
$txts = Get-ChildItem $path\* -Include *.txt -Exclude Baseline.txt
foreach ($txt in $txts)
    {
    Compare-Object -referenceobject $(Get-Content $bline) -differenceobject $(Get-Content $txt) | 
    ft inputobject, @{n = "file"; e = {if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>') {"System"}  else {"Baseline"}}} | 
    Out-File $txt'_has_diff'.csv -Width 256
    Get-ChildItem $path | 
        where {$_.Length -eq 0} | 
        Remove-Item
    }
```

Thank you

Edit:
The Hostnames.csv files I've tried are:

```
HOSTNAME1
HOSTNAME2
```

and

```
"HOSTNAME1","HOSTNAME2"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's not working?

Comment: the Import-Csv in line 2 is not working properly.
I know this because it tries to name the files "@{HOSTNAME1=HOSTNAME2}.csv" instead of just "HOSTNAME1.csv"
and if you get rid of the # on line 7, or just use one hostname, it all works

Comment: I guess I'm confused about how the import is not working - you're using an explicit path name.  Are you saying the imported array is incorrect?

Comment: I guess we need to see a sample of your CSV to know how to help you at this point.

Comment: I've tried the Hostname.csv in a couple different formats. 

Line1: HOSTNAME1 . Line2: HOSTNAME2 . as well as all on one line: "HOSTNAME1","HOSTNAME2"

Comment: You say there is "something wrong with the way it is importing the list of hostnames", but you haven't clarified *what* is wrong--what results are you getting, and how do they differ from the desired results? Also, neither of your examples looks like a CSV file. They both look like lists. A list in which the items are separated by commas is not called a "CSV file". CSV files are a form of ["flat file"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database), in which the data represents the rows and columns of a single database table.

Comment: In fact, I'd wager that whatever it is that's the problem, it probably stems from the fact that you've misunderstood the term "CSV", and you're using **Import-Csv** and **Export-Csv** on non-CSV data.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what the problem is, because you say there is "something wrong with the way it is importing the list of hostnames", but you haven't specified what kind of results you're getting and how they differ from the intended results.

However, based on your sample data I think I can infer what the problem is: You're trying to use **Import-Csv** on non-CSV data. Neither of your examples looks like a CSV file. They both look like lists. A list in which the items are separated by commas, such as

> "HOSTNAME1","HOSTNAME2","HOSTNAME3","HOSTNAME4"

is not called a "CSV file". CSV files are a form of ["flat file"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database), in which the data represents the rows and columns of a single database table. An example of a CSV file would be something like this, where the first line is a list of field (column) names, and the other lines are records (rows) with the comma-separated values corresponding to the columns in the header row:

> "Hostname","OS","OS Version","Primary Function","Location"
>   "BOSEXCH01","Windows","Server 2012","Microsoft Exchange","Boston"
>   "BOSDC01","Windows","Server 2008 R2","Active Directory domain controller","Boston"
>   "MYWEB","Linux","Ubuntu 13.04","Apache web server","Phoenix"

The cmdlet **Import-Csv** imports a CSV file into an array of *objects* in which the properties are the field names in the header row, and the values are the comma-separated items in each row corresponding to the property names derived from the header row. **Export-Csv** does the reverse—it creates a CSV file from an array of objects.

It looks like what you're trying to do is read a simple list of hostnames into an array of strings. If your data looks like the first example,

> HOSTNAME1
>   HOSTNAME2
>   [etc...]

you can read it into an array by simply using **Get-Content**, as follows (note that I changed the extension to **.txt** to reflect the actual format of the data):

```powershell
$computers = Get-Content "\\Path\hostnames.txt"
```

If your data looks like the second example,

> "HOSTNAME1","HOSTNAME2",[etc...]

you can read it into array like this:

```powershell
$computers = (Get-Content "\\Path\hostnames.txt") -split ','
```

On the other hand, it appears that you *are* using **Export-Csv** correctly: You're exporting a bunch of objects with the same properties into a flat file, which is the correct usage of the term "CSV".